# Hibernate : have a eager getter for a distant lazy dependency?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Let's say I have :

```
-----------
|  City   |
-----------
| - id    |
| - name  |
-----------
    (1)
     |
     |
     |
    (*)
-----------
|  Street |
-----------
| - id    |
| - name  |
-----------
    (1)
     |
     |
     |
    (*)
-----------
|  House  |
-----------
| - id    |
| - num   |
-----------
```

So :

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "street", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Street> streets;

}

@Entity
public class Street {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "house", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<House> houses;
}

@Entity
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private int num;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Street street;

}
```

**Here is the question :** I want to get the city name of a house without fetching the city and **keep the lazy loading**. Is there a magic decorator to load 'eagerly' a distant dependency ? Like

```
@Entity
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private int num;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Street street;

    @Magic(from this.street.city.name ?) // <------- HERE
    private String houseName;

}
```

Comment: just keep it lazy, when you call getCity() another request is made and returns the city, there you call getName(), just becarefull of LazyInitializationException

Comment: No, there isn't. You're going to have to use a query